# self click on a <a> element inside function

Tags: javascript, php, yii2

I have to download a file from server and I have this function.

```
private function downloadFile($dir,$file,$alias)
{    
    $path=$dir.$file;
    $name=$alias.".pptx";
    $size = filesize($path);
    header("Content-Type: application/force-download");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='$name'");
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: BINARY");
    header("Content-Length: " . $size);
    // Descargar archivo
    readfile($path);
    Yii::$app->session->setFlash("errordownload");
    exit;
```

But I would like to know if its possible use a self-click  html element instead of headers.

Something like this

```
private function downloadFile($dir,$file,$alias)
{    
    echo '<a id="a" href="'.$dir.$file.'" download="'$alias.".pptx".'" class=" btn btn-primary">Descargar Archivo</a>';

    echo'<script type="text/javascript"> 
            $(document).ready(function(){
               $("#a").click();
            }
          </script>'

}
```

I want to do it through `<a>` because otherwise I get some errors when I try to open the file. The file in server opens with no errors.

Comment: if you use that `downloadFile()` function more than once you'll be generating bad html. `id` must be UNIQUE throughout the entire document. if you generate 2+ download links, only the first one will ever get triggered, because getElementById() will only return ONE dom element, because it's not permitted to have more than one of an id at a time.

Comment: I use it just one at time. Id is unique, There is just one link.